# Error when trying to alter keyspace replication factor with cassandra for system_auth

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to increase my replication factor in cassandra because it is neccesary for security related reasons according to:

http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.0/security/security_keyspace_replication#security-keyspace-replication

When I do the command:

```
ALTER KEYSPACE "system_auth" WITH REPLICATION { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 2};
```

I get the error:

```
Bad Request: line 1:46 missing '=' at {
```

Does someone know why this is? I am confused about this﻿

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alter KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication =  { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 2};`

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#createKeyspaceStmt

Comment: is it normal that it says that system_auth doesnt exist? I can I even view the keyspaces I have defined?

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving similar errors, and here are the steps I went through to get things working for me.

A little about my setup: running four Cassandra servers in AWS. They're named (unoriginally) `cass1` through `cass4`.

1. Changed `cassandra.yaml` on `cass1`. I set `authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator` and `authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer`.
2. Restarted Cassandra on `cass1`.
3. Logged in using `cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra`
4. Ran a **different** `ALTER TABLE` than @mikhail-stepura recommended. I used: `alter KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication =  { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'us-east' : 4};`

   - Running his, I found that I couldn't authenticate on `cass2` through `cass4`. I would get one of two error messages: either

     - `Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': AuthenticationFailed(u'Failed to authenticate to 127.0.0.1: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM"',)})` or
     - `Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, 'ECONNREFUSED')})`
5. I duplicated my changes to `cassandra.yaml` on `cass2` through `cass4`, and restarted Cassandra on each server.
6. Voila! I could log in to Cassandra on all servers.